# How to filter rows with specified conditions in a dataframe and put them in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

The data of test.csv likes this:

```
staff_id,clock_time,device_id,latitude,longitude
1001,2020/9/14 04:43:00,d_1,24.59652556,118.0824644
1001,2020/9/14 05:34:40,d_1,24.59732974,118.0859631
1001,2020/9/14 06:33:34,d_1,24.73208312,118.0957197
1001,2020/9/14 08:17:29,d_1,24.59222786,118.0955275
1001,2020/9/20 05:30:56,d_1,24.59689407,118.2863806
1001,2020/9/20 07:26:05,d_1,24.58237852,118.2858955
1001,2020/9/20 08:26:05,d_1,24.58237852,118.2858955
1001,2020/9/20 09:26:05,d_1,24.58237852,118.2858955
1001,2020/9/20 17:26:05,d_1,24.58237852,118.2858955
1001,2020/9/20 19:26:05,d_1,24.70237852,118.2858955
1001,2020/9/20 22:26:05,d_1,24.71237852,118.2858955
```

I want to find any row where the difference between longitude or latitude of 2 consecutive rows is greater than 0.1,then put the result into a new dataframe.

In my example,the latitude difference of rows 2,3,4,9,10 are greater than 0.1, and the longitude difference of rows 4,5 are greater than 0.1.

I want the new dataframe likes this:

```
staff_id,clock_time,device_id,latitude,longitude
1001,2020/9/14 05:34:40,d_1,24.59732974,118.0859631
1001,2020/9/14 06:33:34,d_1,24.73208312,118.0957197
1001,2020/9/14 08:17:29,d_1,24.59222786,118.0955275
1001,2020/9/20 05:30:56,d_1,24.59689407,118.2863806
1001,2020/9/20 17:26:05,d_1,24.58237852,118.2858955
1001,2020/9/20 19:26:05,d_1,24.70237852,118.2858955
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'E:/test.csv', encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1])
m1 = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].diff().abs().gt(0.1)
m2 = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].shift().diff().abs().gt(0.1)
new_dataframe = [...]
```

How do do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for convert DataFrame of boolean to `Series` and for shifted mask add [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), chain with `|` for bitwise `OR` and last add [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid warning if `new_dataframe` will be processed some way after this filtration:

```
m1 = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].diff().abs().gt(0.1).any(axis=1)

new_dataframe = df[m1 | m1.shift(-1)].copy()
print (new_dataframe)
   staff_id          clock_time device_id   latitude   longitude
1      1001  2020/9/14 05:34:40       d_1  24.597330  118.085963
2      1001  2020/9/14 06:33:34       d_1  24.732083  118.095720
3      1001  2020/9/14 08:17:29       d_1  24.592228  118.095527
4      1001  2020/9/20 05:30:56       d_1  24.596894  118.286381
8      1001  2020/9/20 17:26:05       d_1  24.582379  118.285896
9      1001  2020/9/20 19:26:05       d_1  24.702379  118.285896
```

Comment: May I use `new_dataframe = df[m1 | m1.shift(-1)]`?